# Angular material Snackbar with multiple actions

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible to have multiple actions within an Angular Material snackbar?

I know it is possible to use your own component for the snackbar.

But for this code, the action is only one action

```ts
private snackBar: MatSnackBar;

this.snackBar._openedSnackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(
  () => {
    console.log('action has occurred, but which one?')
  }
);
```

Comment: Material snackbars only support one action

Comment: Snackbars are more for notifications than for actions. If you want actions, consider looking at a modal or bottom sheet

Answer (score 7):

I am using Angular9 and we have an option to use a custom component inside the `SnackBar`. Here is the sample code:

Inside callee component:

```
    openSnackBar(message) {
        this.snackBar.openFromComponent(CustomSnackBarComponent, {
            duration: 5 * 1000,
        });
    }
```

Custom component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'snack-bar-component-example-snack',
    template: `<div class="example-pizza-party">
               <button mat-raised-button (click)="cancel()">Cancel </button>
               <button mat-raised-button (click)="doAction()">View Results </button>
               </div>`,
    styles: [`
      .example-pizza-party {
        color: green;
      }
    `],
  })
  export class CustomSnackBarComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    doAction() {
        // you can do some action here
    }

    cancel() {
      // close the snackbar or wirte another action
    }

  }
```

Refer to the official docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview).

Comment: how do you dismiss this snackbar now?

Comment: A `snackbar` can be dismissed manually by calling the `dismiss` method on the `MatSnackBarRef` returned from the call to `open`. Basically, when we open the snackbar, store the returend reference in a variable, and invoke it from the cancel() function.

Answer (score 4):

**Demo :** [SnackBar created using Bottom Sheet](https://angular-bottomsheet-as-snackbar.stackblitz.io)
I have not found 2 actions working in [SnackBars](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview), but implemented a snackBar with 2 actions using [BottomSheet](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview) Component.

**Scenario :**
 
I had same requirement in the project.

Notifications were displayed using snackBar in the whole project, and for one action, its easy to handle using snackBar.

**Problem :**

- But, there was a requirement of adding 2 or multiple actions in the
  snackBars as notifications were completely handled through snackBars
  in the Project.

**Solution Achieved :**

- Created and styled the BottomSheet in such a manner to replicate the snackbar used in the project.
- **Demo Project :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bottomsheet-as-snackbar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

[image: Click on any tab to open a SnackBar]

**Opened SnackBar :**
[image: Open SnackBar using BottomSheet]

Answer (score -1):

You can hook into the snackbars `MatSnackBarRef.dismiss()` and `MatSnackBarRef.dismissWithAction()` methods. You can for instance do this explicitly by dedicating a button to each of them.

`MatSnackBarRef.afterDismissed()` do something.

`MatSnackBarRef.onAction()` do something else.

(Note the 'third action' in the example below where "Learn more..." is a link to the terms.)

[image: Cookies snackbar]

Answer (score -3):

You can declare the action string (ie **actionSelected**) inside a function, and call that function (**openSnackBar**) whenever you want to open a snackbar just like this:

```
openSnackBar(message: string, action:string, response:any) {
    let actionSelected:string = action;
    let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(message, this.snackbarActions[action], {duration:3000});;
    console.log("response");
    console.log(response);
    snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
        if(actionSelected == "view_sf"){
            window.open('https://eu12.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Lead/'+response.id.toString()+'/view', "_blank");
        }else if(actionSelected == "view_odoo"){
            window.open("https://tienda.prokom.es/web#id="+response["result"].toString()+"&view_type=form&model=crm.lead&action=286");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This isn't a practical answer to this question. Also, @sandeepkumar answer is perfect and here is demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-snackbar-custom?file=app%2Fsnack-bar-component-example.ts